# How do I turn off the Results pane error message when editing a row

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am currently editing data in a table in SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Each time I move to the next row it gives me [image]

Is there anyway to turn this off and it just saves automatically without asking me to commit after every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else posted the correct answer but then they deleted it? not sure why,

The answer was contained here... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925719

I had to convert my text fields to varchar(max)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in SSMS that occurs when:

1. The table contains one or more columns of the text or ntext data
   type.
2. The value of one of these columns contains the following characters:

   - Percent sign (%)
   - Underscore (_)
   - Left bracket ([)
3. The table does not contain a primary key.

Apparently, the SSMS generates an incorrect `UPDATE` statement.
To prevent this error, you should run an `UPDATE` statement in the query window.

Click [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925719?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

---

As the article said, this only happens to the 2005 version. I'll leave it here for reference.

Comment: No worries, you're using 2012 right? Maybe the bug still exists.